# changing the background color of the WPF datepicker

Tags: wpf

I am trying to change the starting background color of a WPF datepicker

right now it looks like: [image]

The XAML looks like

```xml
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
  <DatePicker.CalendarStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
  </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
</DatePicker>
```

the current setter is setting the calendar drop down black.  I would like to set the current background to a darker color.

Comment: I don't understand. What is "a darker color" than the black you are already setting? Please fix your question so that it includes a good [mcve], and provide a more precise explanation of what the code does now, what you want it to do instead, what you've tried already, and what specifically you are having trouble figuring out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the background of the textbox by adding an implicit `DatePickerTextBox` style to `<DatePicker.Resources>`:

```
<DatePicker Background="Black" Margin="4" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Calendar}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.CalendarStyle>
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Silver" />
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: exactly what I needed, Thanks :)